Calling a consteval function within if consteval causes error in non-constexpr context
The following code does not compile with g++ 14.1 or clang++ 18.1:
#include <type_traits>

consteval int
plusone(int n)
{
  return n+1;
}

constexpr int
maybeplusone(int n)
{
  if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
    n = plusone(n);
  }
  return n;
}

int
not_consteval()
{
  return maybeplusone(1);
}

The compiler complains that n is not a constant expression.  If I change the if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) to if consteval, then the code compiles with clang++ but not g++.  My questions:

Why isn't the code valid?

Should if consteval be different from if (std::is_constant_evaluted()), and if so is clang++ correct to accept the code with if consteval?

Is there a better way to define a function like plusone that should not accidentally be called at runtime, but without causing such errors?  Something like static_assert(std::is_runtime_evaluated())--except that's presumably useless as the static assert will always be evaluated at compile time.


For what it's worth, in my more complex application I have different memory allocators for compile time and run time, so I want to do something like this
if consteval {
  p = my_consteval_allocator(n);
}
else {
  p = my_real_allocator(n);
}

with similar logic for deallocation.  Unfortunately, the compiler is trying to call my_consteval_allocator in non-constexpr contexts when it knows the allocation size required.

With if consteval it compiles for me on both GCC and Clang.

With gcc it only compiles when you disable optimization. I should have specified. Add -O and you will see the error.

If if consteval wasn't any different from if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) we wouldn't have added it (we had std::is_constant_evaluated() in C++20, while if consteval was a C++23 feature).

You talked about gcc with optimizations in some comments, so it might be this gcc bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=115583

@Artyer Yes, I think that's the exact bug I'm running into.  Thank you.

@Barry, well, if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) always had the issue that programmers wrote if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated()), which can’t really happen with if consteval.

@Bolpat I'm aware, but compilers warn on that case reliably, so it's at best a minor nuisance - not really a real problem.

if (std::is_constant_evaluted()) is just a completely normal if control flow, only that std::is_constant_evaluted() evaluates to either true or false depending on whether or not the evaluation happens in a context that is manifestly constant-evaluated.
In particular, if a call to a consteval function appears in an if (std::is_constant_evaluted()) branch then, usually, the call to this function must in itself be a constant expression where it appears.
Because n is a function parameter whose value is not known at compile time plusone(n) when the function is defined, it is not a constant expression.
if consteval has stronger semantics. It is known that the first branch of such an if can only ever be executed at compile time and therefore calls to consteval functions appearing within it are not required to be themselves constant expressions. They must only be constant subexpressions when evaluating the whole constant expression that leads to the call of the function containing the if consteval statement.
So, always use if consteval and forget that std::is_constant_evaluted() exists, unless you need to support C++20. But if you need that, then you can't use consteval functions either.
In not_consteval, the call to maybeplusone is not a context that is manifestly constant-evaluated and therefore the runtime branch of if consteval will be chosen. The code is valid with if consteval instead of if(std::is_constant_evaluated()) and it compiles for me on both GCC and Clang.

Regarding your last example: With if consteval it should be fine and the compiler ought to not call my_consteval_allocator except in the context of an evaluation that is manifestly constant-evaluated. The items that can likely give you problems are the special cases for initialization of const integral or enumeration type variables and for static or thread storage duration variables. In these cases constant expression evaluation can happen although it isn't obvious from the syntax.
However, it is a problem that the runtime and compile-time branches have different meaning. You can easily cause an allocation to happen in a manifestly constant-evaluated context, then leak the pointer into a runtime context and accidentally call the runtime deallocation on it. You would always have to manually verify the context in which the functions are called so that they match.
Of course such a leak shouldn't happen. An allocation in a constant expression must also always be deallocated in the same expression. So if my_consteval_allocator uses new, then the compiler will complain about this situation already on the allocation anyway.

This makes sense... So it's a bug that gcc can't compile the if consteval code with optimization.

@user3188445 Yes that looks like a bug. Either it is a constant expression or not. Optimization can't have any impact on it.

Is it really the case that optimization can't have any effect? At least on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated it says compilers may perform a trial constant evaluation, but don't have to.  I know the context is slightly different, but the result could be the same, that the compiler does the trial evaluation only with optimization.

@user3188445 In that special case there is a circularity in the definition: The initialization is manifestly constant-evaluated iff it is a constant expression. The value of std::is_constant_evaluated() is true iff the initialization is manifestly constant-evaluated.

So assuming the initialization in const int a = std::is_constant_evaluated() ? y : 1; is a constant expression, implies that std::is_constant_evaluated() is true, implying that it is not a constant expression because y isn't usable in constant expressions.

On the other hand, assuming it is not a constant expression means that the context is not manifestly constant-evaluated and therefore std::is_constant_evaluated() evaluates to false, implying that the initialization is a constant expression because the access to y doesn't happen. Both are contradictions and I think the standard should be clearer about what will happen in this case. I would be surprised if any compiler chose to make the expression a constant expression in this case.

@user3188445 Similarly in const int b = std::is_constant_evaluated() ? 2 : y; you have the reverse problem that both interpretations as constant expression and as non-constant expression are consistent. Again, this should be clarified, but I would expect compilers to always prefer interpretation as constant expression in this case. In either case I do not expect compilers to make different choices based on optimization.
